# What are the performance analysis measures to validate a face Recognition system?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, video-processing, face-recognition, data-analysis

How to validate the performance of Face Recognition system other than calculating the face recognition rate ?

Comment: face recognition or face detection? So you want to identify special persons or do you want to find out whether there is "any" face in the image? from my intuition, the first task is easier to analyze. The second task can be evaluated similar to http://vision.ucsd.edu/~pdollar/files/papers/DollarPAMI12peds.pdf , see chapter 3

Comment: Thanks for the reference.... But I am feeling sad why people down vote the questions!

Comment: probably because it isnt a programming/code question and has very few text (no images/samples/explanations etc). so it looks like there wasnt much effort in creating this question.

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas:

- You should evaluate how the system behaves with negative examples (faces that are not in the database, things that are not faces at all).
- You should evaluate your algorithm at various recognition thresholds (if such thing applies to your algorithm). If the threshold is too high, the system will reject a lot of people: there will be many true negatives (people who should be rejected will be rejected), but many false negatives too (people who should be recognized won't be recognized). Conversely, if it's too low, there will be many true positives, but many false positives too. So it's a trade-off which can be visualized using a [ROC curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic). To evaluate the "best" threshold, you must consider the application. E.g. when controlling access to a building, it might be better having a more demanding threshold leaving a few legitimate people out, who might have other means of accessing, than risking having a stranger in.

See also:

- [Evaluation of binary classifiers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_of_binary_classifiers)
- [Sensitivity and specificity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivity_and_specificity)